# Update packages included in USN in a offline environment

Tags: apt, upgrade

I need to perform an offline updates to a number of packages (Few USN patches on a ubuntu server 18.04.02)

Here are some examples for packages that need to be updated  :
grub-efi-amd64-bin-2.02-2ubuntu8.14     (needs to be updated to grub-efi-amd64-bin-2.02-2ubuntu8.16)
grub-efi-amd64-signed-1.93.18+2.02-2ubuntu8.14  (needs to be updated to grub-efi-amd64-signed-1.93.18+2.02-2ubuntu8.16)

linux-image-5.3.0-28-generic - 5.3.0-28.30~18.04.1   (needs to be updated to linux-image-5.3.0-62-generic-5.3.0-62.56~18.04.1)

I saw that some of those packages can be downloaded as a source code and as i understand need to be compiled on the server.

My question is : Is it possible/safe to do this kind of upgrdades (compiling the code) on a offline machine? Or it is best to use deb packages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: A fully upgraded *bionic* server will report 18.04.5, and use either a 5.4 (HWE) or 4.15 (GA) kernel and stack. I don't know your *architecture*, and am aware that there are Canonical supported 5.3 builds for specific cases, but that for generic use as it's EOL being replaced by 5.4 for HWE enabled conventional systems. Yes you can build locally, but I'd use *deb* packages myself as far easier/faster, but I'd check your details as 5.3 is no longer a fully-patched kernel unless you're using covered in the supported use-case.

Comment: It's possible, but it's sometimes not easy. One way to make it easier is to use an online test machine. VMs with no data (or dummy data) are particularly handy for this, as they can be snapshotted and rolled back. Learn all your dependency needs and make all your mistakes in the test environment before sneakernetting the changes across to your offline production system.